# Replace one or more spaces in string with '\s+'

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nltk

I would like to replace all spaces in string strings with '\s+'.  Strings may have one or more spaces between words.  The current code that I have tried is:

```
import nltk
string = 'jason   e   n robins inc'
tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(string)
out = '\s+'.join(tokenized)
#expected: 'jason\s+e\s+n\s+robins\s+inc'
#get: 'jason\\s+e\\s+n\\s+robins\\s+inc'
```

The goal is to pass the output through a string parser:

```
import re
other_str = 'some other text where i want to split jason e n robins  inc off the end with other text'
final_output = re.split(other_text, out)[0]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The output is correct.

Comment: I want to get the expected output so that I can then pass the output string through a string parser.

Comment: You can do it now. Your expected string is already in `out`.

Comment: That does work.  Ok. Thanks.